# Include a view dynamically via DataBinding

Tags: android, mvvm, layout, data-binding, layout-inflater

I'm using MVVM design pattern with DataBinding support in it. I have a common list item view for multiple screens in my app but in one of the lists there is a small additional view required in that list item view. So, I want to include or inflate that subView dynamically. Like if a field is set in ViewModel then inflate that view else don't. 
   One cheap solution that I've in my mind is that include that view always but show or hide based upon the need. But I don't want to proceed with this choice until its last option.

Following is partial code:

```
       @BindingAdapter("boxPrivacyTag")
        public static void bindBoxPrivacyTag(final ConstraintLayout parentView, String privacyStatus) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(privacyStatus)) {
                Context context = parentView.getContext();
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                LayoutBoxPrivacyStatusBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.layout_box_privacy_status, parentView, false);
                parentView.addView(binding.getRoot());

                binding.tvPrivacy.setText(privacyStatus);
              }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can make a `BindingAdapter` method and inflate your view dynamically from it.

Comment: Share you code what you've done so far which would be helpful to provide you help you needed.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I've added piece of code

Comment: Is that a working code? Looks like *direct inflation* using `DataBindingUtil` won't work as you've not attached any constraints to your parent view from your inflated child view.

Comment: I've updated the code, it is working for me